# Retornar registros que totalizam valor desejado

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Tenho um tabela nesse formato, com mais N valores e N fornecedores, aproximadamente 100 mil registros, e preciso fazer através de uma consulta ou uma função plpgsql uma forma de pegar todos os numeros de lancamento `num` onde a soma do `valor_conta` totalize 0 (zero) ou onde os registros do campos `debito` e `credito` totalizem o `valor_calculo`. No exemplo abaixo seriam os nums `4302454`, `4304304`, `4330098`, `4330095`. Porém esses registros podem não serem exibidos de forma contínua, e podem estar em valor único. Não há critério em como eles são cadastrados ou exibidos.

> ```
> num(pk)   fornecedor      debito    credito   valor_conta saldo   valor_calculo           
> 4302458 FORNECEDOR1     4.35                4.35        23.47   869.00
> 4302456 FORNECEDOR1     19.12               19.12       23.47   869.00
> 4302454 FORNECEDOR1               435.00    -435.00     23.47   869.00
> 4304304 FORNECEDOR1     460.00              460.00      23.47   869.00
> 4330098 FORNECEDOR1     409.00              409.00      23.47   869.00
> 4330095 FORNECEDOR1               434.00    -434.00     23.47   869.00
> ```

Eu já tentei fazer diversos joins, inclusive da forma abaixo, que pega os registros que que somam o que somam o valor do saldo, mas não funciona da forma devida, quando o registro for único e totalizar o valor do saldo.

```
SELECT 'join'::character(4) as link, a.num, a.debito, a.credito
FROM conta_contabil.staging_livro_razao a 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 'join'::character(4) as link, a.num, a.debito, a.credito
    FROM conta_contabil.staging_livro_razao a 
    WHERE a.fornecedor = 'FORNECEDOR1'
    )b ON join' = b.link AND a.fornecedor = 'FORNECEDOR1'
WHERE a.debito + b.debito = 23.47
```

Alguém conseguiria me ajudar com esse problema?

Comment: a estrutura da tabela é exatamente igual está aí e o campo num (pk) é a chave primária mesmo ? e não se repete, correto ?

Comment: você tem que agrupar pelo fornecedor ?

Comment: sugestão: utilize credito / debito em apenas uma coluna, só variando o sinal dos valores

Comment: e qual a ordenação dos registros ? data ? sequencia ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis então, `num` é a chave primária, não se repete. Sim preciso agrupar pelo `fornecedor`, pois a cada fornecedor há registro e valores diferentes (isso irei tratar com plpgsql). Então, o debito e o crédito estão na coluna `valor_conta`, o debito é positivo e o crédito é negativo. Sobre a ordenação não há. Não há uma regra para zerar o saldo (por exemplo já ordenei pelo `valor_conta` e fui calculando com o próximo valor. Há caso em que encontro o 0 (zero), e há casos que não.

Comment: Tentando simplificar sua necessidade, você quer saber quais são os fornecedores que estão com o saldo 0, é isso ?

Comment: Eu preciso dos registros de cada fornecedor que o saldo totalize zero. Pois nesse exemplo o saldo seria 23.47, preciso setar os registros que deram saldo zero com True. Para quando eu fazer uma nova consulta trouxer só os 2 registros que totalizam 23.47.

Comment: há a possibilidade de mudar a estrutura da tabela ? e qual o significado das colunas `valor_conta`, `saldo`, e   `valor_calculo` porque com os valores que estão ali não faz o menor sentido

Comment: dá uma olhada nesse SQL se te começa a ajudar: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/62113/1

Comment: @RovannLinhalis `valor_conta` é a junção das colunas `debito` e `credito`. Porém o débito é positivo e crédito é negativo. Coluna `saldo` é igual a `SUM(valor_conta)`, já agrupado por fornecedor. E `valor_calculo` é o `SUM(debito) - saldo`, já agrupado por fornecedor. `saldo` e `valor_calculo` servem só para se basear.

Comment: mas se os valores estão iguais em todas as linhas, há algo errado nessa lógica. viu o SQL que coloquei no fiddle ? lá mostra o saldo a cada movimento, que seria o mais lógico

Comment: nessa query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ed913/1 o que você quer é ter somente o último registro, onde o saldo atual chegou a zero ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis os valores é porque como esses dados vieram de um arquivo excel, na ferramenta de ETL, eu já fiz esse cálculo. Não influencia no resultado que quero, e os exibi apenas para demonstrar. Vi seu SQL, mas ainda não me ajudou... vamos pro chat, deixa eu tentar explicar direito.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61117/discussion-between-thiagofred-and-rovann-linhalis).

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que me passou pelo chat, e utilizando a data para ordenar os registros (sim, se precisa do momento em que teve o saldo 0, você precisa ter o registros dos momentos em que aconteceram) fiz a seguinte query:

```
with temp as (
SELECT
row_number() OVER(ORDER BY a.data, a.num) AS i,
a.num, 
coalesce(a.credito,0) as credito,
coalesce(a.debito,0)*-1 as debito,
a.fornecedor
from staging_livro_razao a 
where a.fornecedor = 'FORNECEDOR1'
order by a.data), saldo as
(select 
t.*,
(select sum(x.credito + x.debito) from temp x where x.fornecedor = t.fornecedor and x.i < t.i) as saldo_anterior,
(select sum(x.credito + x.debito) from temp x where x.fornecedor = t.fornecedor and x.i <= t.i) as saldo_atual
from temp t)



select * from saldo;
select * from saldo where saldo_atual = 0;
```

Coloquei no SQLFiddle para ajudar: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ac849/8

**Edit:**

Sua real intenção seria encontrar `n` registros onde a soma desses `n` seria igual a 0. Isso significa que, em 4 registros, teriamos 4! (Fatorial)= 12 possibilidades que deveriam ser verificadas. Em apenas 10 registros, já teríamos 3.628.800 possibilidades, o que resultaria em um processamento pra lá de absurdo.

Utilizando os dados informados, e mais alguns, criei no SQL Fiddle o exemplo que acredito resolver o problema:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f813d/1

onde que, todos os registros anteriores ao registro 10, podem ser descartados sem afetar ao saldo do fornecedor.

Answer (score 0):

Certamente seu problema pode ser resolvido utulizando [Funções de Janela](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html).

Segue um exemplo baseado na sua pergunta:

Estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE staging_livro_razao
(
    num bigint,
    fornecedor text,
    debito real,
    credito real,
    valor_conta real,
    saldo real,
    valor_calculo real,
    data date
);
```

Dados:

```
INSERT INTO staging_livro_razao ( num, fornecedor, debito, credito, valor_conta, saldo, valor_calculo, data ) VALUES (4302458, 'FORNECEDOR1',  4.35, NULL, 4.35, 23.47, 869.00, current_date  - '6 days'::interval );
INSERT INTO staging_livro_razao ( num, fornecedor, debito, credito, valor_conta, saldo, valor_calculo, data ) VALUES (4302456, 'FORNECEDOR1', 19.12, NULL, 19.12, 23.47, 869.00, current_date  - '5 days'::interval );
INSERT INTO staging_livro_razao ( num, fornecedor, debito, credito, valor_conta, saldo, valor_calculo, data ) VALUES (4302454, 'FORNECEDOR1', NULL, 435.00, -435.00, 23.47, 869.00, current_date  - '4 days'::interval );
INSERT INTO staging_livro_razao ( num, fornecedor, debito, credito, valor_conta, saldo, valor_calculo, data ) VALUES (4304304, 'FORNECEDOR1', 460.00, NULL,  460.00, 23.47, 869.00, current_date  - '3 days'::interval );
INSERT INTO staging_livro_razao ( num, fornecedor, debito, credito, valor_conta, saldo, valor_calculo, data ) VALUES (4330098, 'FORNECEDOR1', 409.00, NULL,  409.00, 23.47, 869.00, current_date  - '2 days'::interval );
INSERT INTO staging_livro_razao ( num, fornecedor, debito, credito, valor_conta, saldo, valor_calculo, data ) VALUES (4330095, 'FORNECEDOR1', NULL, 434.00, -434.00, 23.47, 869.00, current_date  - '1 days'::interval );
```

Consulta:

```
SELECT
    tbl.num,
    tbl.valor_conta,
    wfunc.historico,
    CASE WHEN ((wfunc.historico * lag(wfunc.historico,1) OVER (ORDER BY wfunc.data)) > 0) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS zero
FROM
    (SELECT num, data, sum(valor_conta) OVER (ORDER BY data) AS historico FROM staging_livro_razao WHERE fornecedor =  'FORNECEDOR1') AS wfunc 
JOIN
    staging_livro_razao AS tbl ON (tbl.num = wfunc.num )
ORDER BY
    tbl.data;
```

Saída:

[image: dataset]

Comment: Camarada, mas o que seria a coluna `zero`? pois há valores 0 e 1 mas não entendi o que significam.

Comment: @thiagofred Significa se houve ou não uma transição de um valor positivo para um valor negativo (ou vice-versa), ou seja, "se passou pelo zero".